# php within a text string

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Goal: Have the entire column of a database converted into one value to sent it within a text string.

Method API:

```
define('SLACK_WEBHOOK', 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/xxx/xxx');
        $message = array('payload' => json_encode(array('text' => " $row[0] $row[1] $row[2] ")));
        $c = curl_init(SLACK_WEBHOOK);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
        curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);
```

[DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgXnN.png)

Store in array:

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM items");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $row[0] $row[1] $row[2]
```

only returns one item from the DB column.

Comment: `" . <?php $sql ... \n " . }; ?> . "` I'm having trouble understanding what it is exactly that you want to do here.

Comment: there's also no code to support the curl tag.

Comment: sending PHP code to be execute using http POST seems like asking for trouble.

Comment: That is why I would like to interrupt the string, include the php and continue the string. Any other suggestion how to include a always changing number of values within a string, not a static value like the others.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I haven't included the full payload method, it's a slack webhook

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to execute an arbitrary piece of PHP code from a string then [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) is what you are looking for.

However I can only say, **do not do this** especially if you are using user input for the string. Doing so will allow a user to run any PHP against the site and opens you up to all kinds of vulnerabilities. You would be better off providing some form of API that you control to allow access in this way.

Edit:
I found this quote in the first comment on the `eval` page, it sums it all up.

> If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert your json string to an array using php function json_decode. Then you need to modify your array to the required format and then send it to your api (check what format the api can process your data) for further processing.